# ObjC: Put logic within a variable, and queue that variable in an array... daydreaming?

Tags: objective-c, function, queue

I'm trying to translate the following JS code to ObjC; It basically defines a function and store it in an array for later execution:

```
var logic = function() {
    me.removeNode(node);
}
this.queue.push(logic);
```

My ObjC port contains the method: `-(void)removeNode:(AbstractNode*)node` and I'm stuck... I would like to just queue a call to this method using the specified "node" argument...

edit: I'm reading about selectors. It's still blurry, but might help. Somehow. Or not?

Is it even possible, or will I need to find a workaround :-) ?
Thanks!

Solution to this thanks to the community:

```
// Queue declaration
NSMutableArray *IRQ = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];

// Add logic to the queue for delayed execution:
[IRQ addObject:^{ NSLog(@"thanks for the help!"); } ];

// Call later
for (int i = 0; i < [IRQ count]; i++){
     void (^delayedCall)(void) = [IRQ objectAtIndex:i];
     delayedCall();
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 hey interresting class, just read the intro... thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a block:

```
[queue addObject:^{
    [me removeNode:node];
}];
```

Here's [a short introduction to blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html). They are the Objective-C equivalent of anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to do this with function pointers. If your call backs all take the same type and set of  arguments you should be able to write generic code for invoking

Comment: Hey thanks for your input, looks like the solution John Calsbeek provided with just made it work! Have a nice day, thanks again

Comment: Function pointers in C and derived languages don't get to capture values in them, as `me` and `node` are being captured in the JavaScript example.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the NSInvocation class.