# Block Syntax Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, syntax, objective-c-blocks

I've just read this snippet from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278382/916299):

> When you create a block with the `^{}` syntax...

I understand this syntax, and use it regularly, however I inferred from this that there might be other syntaxes that can be used for creating blocks. Are there? If there are, are there any advantages of the different syntaxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By looking [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) I think the only differences are if you use return types/arguments

Comment: This is the concise answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

If your question is about block literal syntax (the one used for anonymous functions), here is the general form

> ^ return type (arguments list) {expressions}

Based on the that, you can omit the return type

> ^ (arguments list) {expressions}

since it can be inferred from the return type. If there is no return value, `void` is the choice.

Furthermore, you can write

> ^ {expressions}

if there are no arguments.

This is the same as

```
^ void (void) { NSLog(@"Something"); }
```

Comment: Why I see sometimes type is before `^`?

Comment: Sorry my bad. By "type" I mean "return type". I read for the past several hours to figure out the block syntax. As far as I learned, block declaration and block literal follows different syntax? In declaration, it's `returnType (^blockName)(argTypeList)`, while in literal, it's `^(returnType)(argList){body}`?

Comment: @Philip007 yes if you use *typedef* for declaration. For further info I suggest this link: http://yannickloriot.com/2011/11/working-with-blocks/. P.S. Upvote too if you find it useful ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link, the cheat sheet is fantastic. But I don't agree with what you said about typedef. I think block declaration can exist without typedef

Comment: And as far as I learned today, block is often used without declaration(a.k.a inline). In situations like using the same block in multiple places, use typedef to make code look prettier. I hope I got it right..